# Video from RecordRTC not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I have created a WordPress plugin that records reviews in video format with VideoJS (JS library). I am using Video.JS 7.14.3 with Video.JS-Record 4.5.0 and RecordRTC 5.6.2.

I am facing an error on the Safari browser, as seen in the image below:

- When I click on the video to record it throws an error.
- The videos that I previously recorded in a different browser do not play on Safari. The same issue happens anytime I try to play the recorded video.

[image]

Comment: Check the format of your "saved" video recordings in a tool like VLC Player or MediaInfo (or FFmpeg if you have it). Safari only plays MP4 video files that contains H264 video codec and AAC audio codec. Most browser "recorders" usually make WebM files with VP8 or VP9 video codecs. VP8/9 does not work in Safari. **note:** In past research (last year) I came across some info that Safari can now record to WebM when in RTC mode (still doesn't mean the file can play in Safari, just made there). For that option you might need latest update to your OS and also update Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this issue as could not figure out what was happening.  I discovered there are two things at work here.  There is the mimetytpe being set through the recordrtc call and the container coming from hardware or OS or browser (don't really know but not controllable).

Hence code that sets this to mp4 may not be playable because of the container.

```
  this.recorder = new RecordRTC(this.stream, {
  type: 'video',
  mimeType: 'video/mp4',
  audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
  videoBitsPerSecond: 128000,
  });
```

Note video/mp4 in the code pasted.

And then there is the container that seems to be set by the hardwar/OS/browser.

Note through chorme on windows recrodrtc shows:  `video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus -> 650 KB`

On iOS it is mp4.

That has meant that recording a video to be used across devices appears to require actually conversion using a tool.